# Swapping string case in Python

Tags: python

I'm rank new in Python, thus the question,

I'm trying to solve a simple problem, where the program takes in a simple string and swaps all the cases. Thus if we enter

```
SimPLE
```

We should get

```
sIMple
```

This is my code

```
def main():
    oldStr = input()
    for s in oldStr:
        if s.islower():
            s.upper()
        elif s.isupper():
            s.lower()
    print(oldStr)
if __name__ == "__main__" : main()
```

It just returns the same string. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a generator expression:

```
mystr = "SimPLE"
print("".join(c.upper() if c.islower() else c.lower() for c in mystr))
```

The breakdown of the above is:

```
c.upper() if c.islower() else c.lower()
```

is an conditional expression that will convert a character from upper to lower case and vice versa.

Then,

```
(... for c in mystr)
```

is a generator expression, which is somewhat like a list that is generated on-the-fly.

Finally:

```
".join(...)
```

will join any sequence of strings together with nothing ("") between them.

Comment: I know the OP used `str` as a variable name, but you should change it in an answer.

Comment: @Brian got the str part. Could you explain the code a little more.

Comment: @Zeus updated with explanation - hope that helps!

Answer (score 4):

Do this in one fell swoop with a string join on a list comprehension of individual characters:

```
outstr = ''.join([s.upper() if s.islower() else s.lower() for s in oldStr])
print(outstr)
```

Input & Output:

```
sIMple
SimPLE
```

Comment: Could you explain the code a bit, as stated earlier, I've a Java background and is generally used to more verbose code.

Comment: I know the OP used `str` as a variable name, but you should change it in an answer.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 why can't I use the name str? Is it some pythonic convention?

Comment: @Zeus - see my answer (@Brian) above.

Answer (score 2):

Strings are immutable. What this means is that when you use the function `s.upper()`, it is not setting that letter in `str` to be uppercase, it simply returns that letter in uppercase.

Here is some code that works:

```
def main():
    oldStr = input()
    newStr = ""
    for s in oldStr:
        if s.islower():
            newStr+=s.upper()
        elif s.isupper():
            newStr+=s.lower()
    print(newStr)
```

Notice now that we are creating a new string and simply adding the letters at each point in the forloop as opposed to changing those letters in `str`.

Comment: I know the OP used `str` as a variable name, but you should change it in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are running each character through `lower()` and `upper()`, but these functions do not *change* the character.

Instead, they **return** the modified version of the character. The original character `s` will stay as it is.

You should build a new string based off the *return values* of `lower()` and `upper()`, and return that string.

Answer (score 0):

1) you need to put the `main()` call on  new line, as python relies on whitespace heavily for program structure

2) s is a temporary variable created for the purpose of the for statement. It doesn't actually reference the character in the string

Essentially what is going on is that `s` has the same value as the character in the string, but it **IS NOT ACTUALLY** the character in the string.

Comment: The `main()` call does not need to be on a new line.

Comment: It doesn't? Whenever I don't put stuff on a new line, all it does is error. Also when I don't indent.

Comment: See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html) and [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html).